# android differentiate between bluetooth hard keyboard and barcode scanner on key event

Tags: android

So I have the following code which differentiates between soft keyboard entry and a Bluetooth barcode scanner...

```
               if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    if(event.getDeviceId()==-1) //from soft keyboard
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

                    char pressedKey = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
                    barCode += pressedKey;
                }
                if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    if(event.getDeviceId()==-1) //from keyboard
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

                    String giftCardUPC = barCode.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
                    fragmentProShopGiftCard.etUPCCode.setText(giftCardUPC);
                    barCode="";
                }
```

the idea is that the barcode scanner has a device ID and the soft keyboard does not.  The problem now is I have an activity that supports both a HARD bluetooth keyboard, soft keyboard (if they don't use a hard keyboard), as well as a barcode scanner.

Is there any way to differentiate between the 2 hardware devices on dispatchKeyEvent?

Comment: The perennial question arises: why?

Comment: it's a POS system and there is an activity that "rings up" gift cards to sell to the customer.  User needs to scan a new gift card to get the UPC code, there is also a hard keyboard so the user can enter customer name and other info.  When the store gets busy, the soft keyboard is just way too slow.

Comment: So basically you're trying to audit efficiency?

Comment: I'm trying to satisfy business requirements for my clients.

Comment: Can you tell us what the exact requirement is?
Is this a security measure to prevent entering gift card code manually, or just a way to automate / filter input?
If its the latter, there may be better ways to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: They should have the option to scan or enter manually.  Currently the hardware keyboard doesn't enter any text in the edittext because the event.getDeviceId() has an ID when it's a hard keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing...I noticed that the barcode scanner's first entry was always a KeyCode of KEYCODE_LEFT_SHIFT....

```
String barCode = "";
boolean barCodeMode = false;
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    if(event.getDeviceId()==-1) { //from soft keyboard
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
                    }else if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT || barCodeMode){ //from barcode scanner
                        barCodeMode = true;
                        char pressedKey = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
                        barCode += pressedKey;
                    }else{ //from hard keyboard
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
                    }
                }
                if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    if(event.getDeviceId()==-1) { //from soft keyboard
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
                    }else if(barCodeMode){ //from barcode scanner
                        String giftCardUPC = barCode.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
                        fragmentProShopGiftCard.etUPCCode.setText(giftCardUPC);
                        barCode="";
                        barCodeMode = false;
                    }else{ //from hard keyboard
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are other fields in the activity (or a previous activity or fragment) where the user is expected to perform manual input, you could check and save the device ID there, and later compare it to the device ID used for the input you're interested in.

Another possibility would be to record the timing of the key events. A barcode reader will be much faster than anyone can type.

Comment: Does the device ID ever change?  For example if the device runs out of battery power, will it get assigned a new device id?  Where should I save the device ID, in shared preferences?

Comment: Android documentation of getDeviceId says "The other numbers are arbitrary and you shouldn't depend on the values."
I am only guessing, but the ID may change every time devices are reconnected, switched off and on, or the host (your POS) is rebooted.

Comment: good grief, you would think there would be a way to get a mac address or something of these devices so you could ID them

Comment: @TKK if I go the timing route, do i just time between key down and key up?

Comment: @Jarrette I was thinking between consecutive key downs.